# Show user's mapped drives through PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find or build a script through PowerShell that will create a report showing users mapped drives on the domain.

I found this command to pull the drives and paths:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Select-Object name, @{n="Root"; e={if ($_.DisplayRoot -eq $null) {$_.Root} else {$_.DisplayRoot}}}
```

but now I'm trying to figure out how to use PowerShell to scan the users on the network.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
( Get-ADComputer -Filter * ).Name | 
% { Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock { Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | 
        Select-Object name, @{n="Root"; e={if ($_.DisplayRoot -eq $null) {$_.Root} else {$_.DisplayRoot}}}
     }
 }
```